# Remove TOC in RTF doxygen output

Tags: doxygen

Is there a way to remove the TOC from the RTF output generated by doxygen?

[image: TOC in RTF output from doxygen]

Comment: As far as I can see in the code there is no way to automatically remove the Table of Contents of a RTF file in doxygen output. The only thing one can do is edit it out by hand (either with a text editor from the rtf file or in word / openoffice / ...).

Comment: @albert I was afraid you were going to say that ;)  I have several docs being created, so I guess I can create a python script to remove it.  But I was hoping I could just uncheck a box in Doxygen.

Comment: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8042 created for this issue.