# Remove Index in RTF doxygen output

Tags: doxygen

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928769/remove-toc-in-rtf-doxygen-output)

Is there a way to remove the Index from the RTF output generated by doxygen?

[image]

Comment: You are probably afraid of the answer I will give: As far as I can see in the code there is no way to automatically remove the Index. So at the moment the same edit possibility exists as in the similar question for TOC. At first glance when looking at the, doxygen, code it would be easier to get ride of this index than the TOC, but this would require a new configuration setting (this setting could simultaneous also work for the other "book" output formats, i.e. LaTeX and docbook) but would require an enhancement issue in the doxygen issue tracker.

Comment: @albert That's kind of what I figured, but I like to put these things up here in case others have similar issues/problems ;)  I will create a couple issues in Github for both features.  I can probably get around both issues with a python script, but the less scripting I have to do the better ;)

Comment: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8043 created for this issue.